# DNS config has no effect

Tags: macos, vpn, osx-yosemite, cisco-vpn-client

Neither this `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
domain example.com
nameserver 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver 130.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Nor this `scutil` output:

```
$ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : example.com
  search domain[1] : example.lan
  nameserver[0] : 172.xxx.xxx.xxx
  if_index : 11 (en4)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address

resolver #2
  domain   : example.com
  nameserver[0] : 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
  nameserver[1] : 130.xxx.xxx.xxx
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
  order    : 100400

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : xxx.lan
  nameserver[0] : 172.xxx.xxx.xxx
  if_index : 11 (en4)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address

resolver #2
  search domain[0] : example.com
  nameserver[0] : 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
  nameserver[1] : 130.xxx.xxx.xxx
  if_index : 10 (utun0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

are helping with resolution of names through the `utun0` interface to example.com's VPN. The VPN itself is working, because I can ping IPs only accessible through the VPN, and manual DNS name resolution works:

```
$ nslookup yyy.example.com 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
Server:     192.xxx.xxx.xxx
Address:    192.xxx.xxx.xxx#53

yyy.example.com canonical name = yyy.example.com.
Name:   yyy.example.com
Address: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

but Chrome, ping, etc. don't like resolving the host:

```
$ ping yyy.example.com
ping: cannot resolve yyy.example.com: Unknown host
```

Host doesn't work:

```
$ host yyy.example.com
Host yyy.example.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

The configuration all appears correct to me - 172 is my local LAN, 192 and 130 are the VPN DNS servers. For a number of reasons, I'm using `openconnect` instead of the Cisco AnyConnect Mobility client.

More output:

```
$ sudo discoveryutil configresolvers
Password:
Configuration Resolvers: Resolver domain [default], type Unicast, ifIndex 11, port 0, timeout 30, A yes, AAAA no, serviceID 0, scope None, order 0
  server 172.16.0.1
  search domain(s) example.com, example.lan
Configuration Resolvers: Resolver domain example.com, type Unicast, ifIndex 0, port 0, timeout 30, A yes, AAAA no, serviceID 0, scope None, order 100400
  server(s) 192.xxx.xxx.xxx, 130.xxx.xxx.xxx
Configuration Resolvers: Resolver domain [default], type Unicast, ifIndex 11, port 0, timeout 30, A yes, AAAA no, serviceID 0, scope InterfaceID, order 0
  server 172.16.0.1
Configuration Resolvers: Resolver domain [default], type Unicast, ifIndex 10, port 0, timeout 30, A yes, AAAA no, serviceID 0, scope InterfaceID, order 0
  server(s) 192.xxx.xxx.xxx, 130.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Relevant code from the open connect script that does the scutil can be found here : [vpnc-script](http://git.infradead.org/users/dwmw2/vpnc-scripts.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/vpnc-script)

Comment: check /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: I have no such file :/

Comment: Aaa, its MacOS, have you try to restart mDNSResponder?

Comment: I don't have mDNSResponder - Yosemite replaced it with `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist` . Restarting that didn't help.

Comment: Several notes: Yosemite's resolver (discoveryd, not mDNSResponder) doesn't read /etc/resolv.conf, so that's not relevant. `nslookup` uses /etc/resolv.conf instead of the system resolver, so it's not a good test. How did you set the info in `scutil`? I'd also check the output of `sudo discoveryutil configresolvers`.

Comment: scutil was set via the automatic execution of this script: http://git.infradead.org/users/dwmw2/vpnc-scripts.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/vpnc-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I got this to work was to manually call `networksetup -setdnsservers`. Once I have a functional vpnc-script I'll post it to the InfraDead openconnect forum.